# runwhen scheduler not picking the command in the script

Tags: linux

I'm using `runwhen` scheduler for scheduling a job in one of our servers.My script has `uaac` command in it. But, when I schedule the script with runwhen, the `uaac` commands in my script are being skipped. I've installed uaac as a ruby gem. Tried absolute path for `uaac` also. Still fails.

Looking forward for a expert suggestion.

Regards, Prasad

Comment: Share your script, how can we help you without knowing what exactly you have done?

Comment: Please consider my script has only this content : `uaac context` and it fails.

Comment: this is the runwhen log : `2018-08-03 08:51:01.704805500 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.4.0/gems/cf-uaac-3.12.0/lib/uaa/cli/token.rb:157:in `join': no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
`

Comment: That means that it does run and your problem is with the gem itself and not with runwhen. To translate the ruby error further - it's trying to work with something that was not given. So, a property or env variable of some sort is missing in the context of your script and therefore the gem fails.